# VB.NET/ import namespaces from codeDOM compiler

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, namespaces, stub, codedom

I encounter an error while compiling a project containing the import of a namespace.
I have a file called "`Dissimulation.vb`" in which the namespace "`Dissimulation2`" is declared. Here is his code:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off


Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Namespace Dissimulation2

    Public Class La
        Public Shared Function variable_17(ByVal variable_55 As Byte(), ByVal variable_56 As Byte()) As Byte()
            '///AES FUNCTION///
            Dim variable_57 As Byte() = Nothing
            Dim variable_58 As Byte() = New Byte() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
            Using variable_59 As New MemoryStream()
                While True
                    Using variable_60 As New RijndaelManaged
                        variable_60.KeySize = 256
                        variable_60.BlockSize = 128
                        Dim variable_61 = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(variable_56, variable_58, 10000)
                        Dim test As New CryptoStreamMode
                        Do
                            test = CryptoStreamMode.Write
                            variable_60.Key = variable_61.GetBytes(variable_60.KeySize / 8)
                            variable_60.IV = variable_61.GetBytes(variable_60.BlockSize / 8)
                            variable_60.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
                            Using variable_62 = New CryptoStream(variable_59, variable_60.CreateDecryptor(), test)
                                variable_62.Write(variable_55, 0, variable_55.Length)
                                variable_62.Close()
                                variable_57 = variable_59.ToArray
                                Return variable_57
                            End Using
                            Exit Do
                        Loop
                    End Using
                End While
            End Using
        End Function
    End Class


End Namespace
```

In the mother file, entitled "`Source.vb`" I would like to call this function. To do this, I simply take it like this:

```
Dissimulation2.La.variable_17(variable_8, variable_9)
```

Visual Basic does not tell me any errors at this time.
Nevertheless, when I compile everything via CodeDOM, I encounter the following error:

```
"BwkFvmB7" is not a member of 'Dissimulation2.La'.
```

Here are the parameters of CodeDOM:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.CodeDom
Public Class Codedom

    Public Shared Function compile_Stub(ByVal input As String, ByVal output As String, ByVal resources As String, ByVal showError As Boolean, Optional ByVal icon_Path As String = Nothing) As Boolean

        Dim provider_Args As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        provider_Args.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0")

        Dim provider As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider(provider_Args)
        Dim c_Param As New Compiler.CompilerParameters
        Dim c_Args As String = " /target:winexe /platform:x86 /optimize "

        If Not icon_Path = Nothing Then
            c_Args = c_Args & "/win32icon:" & icon_Path
        End If

        c_Param.GenerateExecutable = True
        c_Param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.Dll")
        c_Param.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.Dll")
        c_Param.GenerateInMemory = True
        c_Param.OutputAssembly = output

        c_Param.EmbeddedResources.Add(resources)
        c_Param.CompilerOptions = c_Args
        c_Param.IncludeDebugInformation = False

        Dim c_Result As Compiler.CompilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(c_Param, input)
        If c_Result.Errors.Count = 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            If showError Then
                For Each _Error As Compiler.CompilerError In c_Result.Errors
                    MessageBox.Show("ERREUR de compilation" & vbNewLine &
                  "FileName: " & _Error.FileName & vbNewLine &
                  "Line: " & _Error.Line & vbNewLine & "ErrorText: " &
                  _Error.ErrorText & vbNewLine &
                  "Column: " &
                  _Error.Column & vbNewLine &
                  "Error Type: " &
                  _Error.IsWarning & vbNewLine & "ErrorNumber: " &
                  _Error.ErrorNumber)
                Next
                Return False
            End If
            Return False
        End If

    End Function
End Class
```

While Visual Basic imports namespaces by default, I guess this is not the case for CodeDOM. So, I guess that error appears. However, I do not know how to import it manually: I can not find any document about it in VB.NET.
Can you point me to the right path?

I have found this question but i do not understand because the code is not codded in VB.NET:

> [Import namespaces in a CodeSnippetCompileUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544634/import-namespaces-in-a-codesnippetcompileunit)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

With

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
```

nothing is checked at compile time. Put both on and then I assume you get the error in Visual Studio, too.

I recommend to *always* use

```
Option Explicit On
```

and *normally* use

```
Option Strict On
```

with the exception of COM interop where sometimes `Option Strict Off` is required (Hint: Don't make your whole class `Option Strict Off`, make two partial classes and compile whatever is not interop with `Option Strict On`).

Comment: Your solution removes the error but function variable_17 is not really called: c Or at least nothing happens when I call it